# Setting name and path of mex file in MATLAB script

Tags: matlab, output, mex

I want to control the path and resulting file name of a mex file.

This is how my build command looks at the moment:

```
sourceFilePath = [tempname,'.cpp']; libDir = ['-L' libDir];  libName = ['-l' libName]; headerDir = ['-I' headerDir];

mex(headerDir,libDir,sourceFilePath,libName);
```

This works fine. But now I want to use a custom mex file name and a custom path.

I saw in the [official docu](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html) that there are the options **-outdir** and **-output**. So I tried to at those in a similar way:

```
outputDir = ['-outdir ' tempdir];

mex(headerDir,libDir,sourceFilePath,libName,outputDir);
```

I also tried it without the space. But I get this error:

> Error using mex Unknown MEX argument '-outdir
>   C:\Users\SELMAO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\'.

Same problems appear when I try to use the **-output** option.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I use `-outdir` no problem in my code...

Comment: Do you see some difference between your and my implementation?

Comment: I just call it as `mex -someoptions  ./folder1/file1.cpp ./folder2/file2.cpp -outdir ./somefolder`

Comment: I need to use the form mex() since I have to use variables for my paths. So this does not help me yet. :(

Comment: It should be the same thing, I just gave you the way I do it and works

Comment: well, for me it doesn't

Comment: Then either you have a very very unique MATLAB version or you are calling it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange.

If I set the option inline it works. If I set it, as before, as a whole variable it does not.

```
mex(headerDir,libDir,sourceFilePath,libName,'-outdir',tempname);
```

This might help others.

Answer (score 1):

You calling it wrong in your example in the opening question:

```
 outputDir = ['-outdir ' tempdir];

 mex(headerDir,libDir,sourceFilePath,libName,outputDir);
```

should be:

```
outputDir = {'-outdir' tempdir};

mex(headerDir,libDir,sourceFilePath,libName,outputDir{:});
```

The reason its wrong is that you are combining the two commands into a single string which the mex correctly refuses.